# changing ui theme color and mouse click to mouse over?

Tags: jquery-ui

1. I have a dropdown menu using FGMenu it uses jquery UI. Where I can change the default color of my dropdown in UI theme so that it will default to color blue instead of gray?
2. The current set-up of drop down is when you click the parent title how to change to mouse over to show the childs of a parent. heres the link. http://christianruado.comuf.com/menu/menu.html

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [Theme Roller](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/). There are plenty of pre-made themes there, and its fully customisable.